# why n*(n+1)/2 % 2 is equivalent to bitwise operation (n+1) & 2 in if condition?

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit-manipulation

update again:sorry to put a wrong link which requires to login...you can see the code now

update:sorry to mislead...already edited the title

---

there is a [problem](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1092) :

> divide the sequence `1 ... n` into 2 sequences which have the same sum, such as... you can divide `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]` into `[1 6 7]` and `[2 3 4 5]`, but not all sequences from 1 to n could divide like that, apparently if the sum of 1 to n, which is `n*(n+1)/2`, if this value is a odd number, it is impossible to do that.

but I want to know, why the condition `[n*(n+1)/2 % 2]` could be replace by `[(n+1) & 2]`?

I see this in the [website](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GfVG9R67zj/)

the problem website is : https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1092

and that code is here :https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GfVG9R67zj/

```
///2021-06-17 02:21:43  SchizoYoshi C++17   0.10 s
///paste from https://cses.fi/problemset/hack/1092/entry/2352488/
#include <iostream>
auto& c = std::cout;

int main() {
    int n, i{};
    std::cin >> n;
    if (++n & 2)
        c << "NO ";
 
    c << "YES " << n-- / 2 << ' ';
    while (n - i++)
        if (i - n & 2)
            c << i << ' ';
    c << n-- / 2 << ' ';
    while (--i)
        if (n - i & 2)
            c << i << ' ';
}
```

Comment: They're not equivalent. Why do you think they are? The "website" link leads to a blank page for me, so I'm not sure what you see there. Could you copy and paste whatever's there here so we don't have to login to view it?

Comment: They are not equal, try `n=2`.

Comment: They can't always be equal. The possible values of `n*(n+1)/2 % 2` are 0 and 1; the possible values of `(n+1) & 2` are 0 and 2

Comment: I am sorry to mislead... they are in if condition

Comment: They are equal as conditions. if both are passed into a condition, both will execute the same branch, which is specified in the question

Comment: They are not equal in `if` either, see `n=2`.

Comment: @Quimby I just did. [See for yourself](https://godbolt.org/z/hnxM3Y13r)

Comment: @Quimby for `n = 2`, `n(n+1)/2 %2 = (2*3/2)%2 = 3%2 = 1` and `(n+1)&2 = 3&2 = 2` both of which satisfy the if condition

Comment: @susanth29 @Lala4=5th, sorry you are correct.

Comment: sorry that put a wrong link....now fixed it...really sorry....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`n*(n+1)/2 % 2 == 0` effectively tests whether `n` or `n+1` is divisible by 4; whether it can be divided by 2 twice. Indeed, there are two possibilities; if `n` is even, then `n+1` is odd, so the only way to divide by 2 twice is to have `n` divisible by 4. Similarly, if `n` is odd, then `n+1` is even and must be divisible by 4 for the condition to hold.

Similarly, `(n+1) & 2 == 0` tests whether either `n` or `n+1` is divisible by 4. It tests that the second lowest bit is zero in `n+1`. If the lowest bit is also zero, then `n+1` is divisible by 4 (it looks like `X00` in binary, so can be shifted two bits right without generating a carry). If the lowest bit in `n+1` is 1, then the lowest bit in `n` is zero, and then `n` is of the form `X00` and is divisible by 4.

Answer (score 3):

The lower 2 bits of n(n+1) and (n+1) are determined by the lower 2 bits of n.  There are only 4 possibilities for the lower 2 bits of n, so you can just check them all to make sure that the two expressions correspond:

```
n%4   (n+1)%4   n(n+1)%4   (n+1)&2   n(n+1)/2%2   
---   -------   --------   -------   ----------
 0       1         0          0          0
 1       2         2          2          1
 2       3         2          2          1
 3       0         0          0          0
```

Yup, it works just fine.